# How can i consume a graphql api with ASP .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I have a app in ASP .NET Framework 4.6

I want to consume a graphql in the best way, adding some library or something method.

in effect to have another alternative, like doing a POST request is acceptable

**(any example of reference will be appreciated)**

I found a post but i asume it doesn't work for me, because is in .net Core

[Consuming a GraphQL API with ASP.NET Core](https://code-maze.com/consume-graphql-api-with-asp-net-core/)!

I want something like this, having my class `Owner`

```
public async Task<List<Owner>> GetAllOwners()
{
    var query = new GraphQLRequest
    {
        Query = @"
                query ownersQuery{
                  owners {
                    id
                    name
                    address
                    accounts {
                      id
                      type
                      description
                    }
                  }
                }"
    };

    var response = await _client.PostAsync(query);
    return response.GetDataFieldAs<List<Owner>>("owners");
}
```

Comment: How are you making the HTTP call, or are you using a library like [dotnet-graphql-client](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client)?

Comment: i dont have any code implemented now, i want a example or references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [GraphQL.Client](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client) library to make the HTTP calls and translate the request/response. That library supports (among others) [.Net Standard 1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.Client).

.Net Standard 1.3 is [supported by .Net Framework 4.6 (and higher)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support). This means you can include the package in a 4.6 Framework project.

You won't be able to use all of the Core-specific paradigms in the blog post, but you'll be able to use that specific library's methods.

Comment: Thanks, but i got stucked in the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup.cs`, in .NET Core works adding some scopes (configuring `GraphQLClient`) and the `AddScoped<OwnerConsumer>()`, this method `ConfigureServices` doesn't exists in my project

Comment: Yeah, the whole configuration system is different in Framework than in Core. That's the part you'll need to learn about how it works in Framework (which is too broad of a topic to cover here).

Comment: Yes. Follow the same steps I outlined in the post to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to use the GraphQL Client for the .NET Framework but didn't have much luck. In the end, I simply used the HttpClient passing in the GraphQL query as a string.